# GCP Cloud Run for Anthos - PERMISSION_DENIED when deploying service with gcloud run deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I successfully followed this [quick-start](https://cloud.google.com/kuberun/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy-gke)  which uses Cloud Run GUI to deploy a Cloud Run for Anthos service.

Then, I wanted to deploy a Cloud Run for Anthos service using `gcloud run deploy` command directly from the Cloud Shell on the GCP website instead of Cloud Run GUI.
I got the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to get service [resourcesettings.googleapis.com]
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: '110002'
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

`gcloud --version` returns:

```
Google Cloud SDK 340.0.0
alpha 2021.05.07
app-engine-go 1.9.71
app-engine-java 1.9.88
app-engine-python 1.9.91
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.91
beta 2021.05.07
bigtable
bq 2.0.67
cbt 0.9.0
cloud-build-local 0.5.2
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2021.05.07
datalab 20190610
gsutil 4.61
kind 0.7.0
kpt 0.39.2
local-extract 1.0.0
minikube 1.19.0
pubsub-emulator 0.4.0
skaffold 1.23.0
```

I do not understand how I was able to deploy through the GUI but not through Cloud Shell CLI (using same GKE cluster, same service name, same Docker image).

Note: `gcloud run deploy` worked with `gcloud config set run/platform managed` instead of `gcloud config set run/platform gke`.
It seems that it is a GKE/Anthos-related issue.

Note 2: It is a small 1-person GCP project, i just created it for Cloud Run for Anthos testing. I have the Owner role.

Comment: What's th version of your gcoud CLI?

Comment: Hi Guillaume,  Google Cloud SDK version is 340.0.0.

Comment: Are you executing the command directly from the Cloud Shell on the GCP website or though a deployment or your local device? Can you also add the result of this command on your post `gcloud --version`.

Comment: Is your project part of an organization managed by somebody else? If so, you simply might not have permission to do this. (That's what Resource Settings API seems to be also about.)

Comment: May be you can try this either [Source](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/setup)